# Conditioned Random Poisson Variables in Python

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, python

In Python I would like to generate a set $X_1,..,X_n$ of random variables whose distribution is that of $n$ i.i.d. Poisson random variables with mean $1$ conditioned on

$$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i = n-1 $$
and
$$1 + \sum_{j=1}^{t} \left( X_j -1\right) > 0 \text{ for all } t \in\{1,..,n-1 \}$$
At the moment I keep generating a set, check the conditions and throw it away until I find one that does satisfy these conditions.
Is there any way to immediately generate a set that satisfies (at least one of) these conditions?

Comment: Maybe this would help you- https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/415794-generate-poisson-numbers-which-sum-a-certain-value

Comment: This appears to be a question about how to implement an algorithm in python, rather than a question about the underlying mathematics.  As such, it is not on-topic here.  I might be more on-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code only ensures the constraint set (1) that requires $1 + \sum_{j=1}^{t} \left( X_j -1\right) > 0$, for all $t \in\{1,..,n-1 \}$,

i.e., $\sum_{j=1}^{t} X_j  > t - 1 \text{ for all } t \in\{1,..,n-1 \}$.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

np.random.seed(111)

n = 1000
s = 0
X = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    X_i = np.random.poisson(1, 1)[0]
    while s + X_i <= i - 1: # constraint set (1)
        X_i = np.random.poisson(1, 1)[0]
    s += X_i
    X.append(X_i)
plt.hist(X)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, in order to ensure the constraint (2) $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i = n-1$ additionally (along with (1) ), we can try the following:

```
np.random.seed(1)

n = 1000
X = np.random.poisson(1, n)
while (not all(np.cumsum(X[:-1]) > range(n-1))) or (not np.sum(X) == n - 1):
    X = np.random.poisson(1,n)

all(np.cumsum(X[:-1]) > range(n - 1)) # constraint set (1)
# True
np.sum(X) == n - 1 # constraint (2)
# True

plt.hist(X)
plt.show()
```

[image]

On average, the second code fragment will be much slower that the first one, since it's hard to satisfy the last constraint along with the first constraint set.